# jQuery change selected attr of form and submit form onchange

Tags: jquery, forms

I am going to be very surprised if this question is not a repeat question. I have searched for a while for the answer to this question but I have not found it. If this question has been asked before I am sorry for asking it again and it would be great if you could point me to the question that already answers this question.

Anyways, I am trying to use jQuery to submit a form once it is changed. That part is working just fine. The part that is not working fine is changing the select attr when the form is changed. The goal is simple: every time the form is changed the value that it is changed to should be given a selected attr of true then the form should be submitted.

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drop Down</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id='example' method='GET' action='index.php'>
            <select id='menu' name='family'>
                <option value='Kristen'>Kristen</option>
                <option value='Henk'>Henk</option>
                <option value='Andrew'>Andrew</option>
                <option value='Derek'>Derek</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').change(function() {
        //remove the select attr from the option that currently has a value of selected
        $("option[selected='true']").removeAttr('selected');
        //add the selected attr with value of true to the option that was clicked on
        $(this).attr('selected', 'true');
        //submit the form
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
```

The form is submitting when the value is changed but the selected attr is not changing. I know the selected attr is not changing because the first value, Kristen, is always shown as the default after the form submits.

Thanks in advance for answers, and I am sorry again if this ends up being a repeat question - meanwhile I will keep searching for answers.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nfR2r/1/ - the value of the attribute seems to be resetted to `selected` instead of `true` in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't save last selected value , the default selected value is the first value in options.

If you want to keep last selected attribute , you can use cookie or use PHP code check selected value after submit page

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) in your case:

```
if($.cookie('selectVal') != null) {
    $('#menu option[value="' + $.cookie('selectVal') + '"]').prop('selected', true);
}

$('#menu').change(function() {
    $.cookie('selectVal', $('#menu option:selected').val(), { expires: 7, path: '/'});
    $(this).find("option[selected='true']").removeAttr('selected');
    $(this).find('option:selected').prop('selected', 'true');
    this.form.submit();
});
```

Comment: When I included this within the document.ready function I got an error. The form did not submit at all. I put an alert under the form submit to see if it even got to that point and it did not. Does this bit of code contain a syntax error that I am missing or was it wrong to include it within the document.ready function?

Comment: I'm not tested this code, btw what is the specific error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the selected option element, `this` inside the change handler refers the select element not the option element which was selected.

You can use the [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').change(function() {
        //remove the select attr from the option that currently has a value of selected
        $(this).find("option[selected='true']").removeAttr('selected');
        //add the selected attr with value of true to the option that was clicked on
        $(this).find('option:selected').attr('selected', 'true');
        //submit the form
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nfR2r/)

Comment: i don't think he need this, just submit the form away. his problem is showing the selected stuff back when the page is reloaded, which must be done on the back code

Comment: This works in Fiddle. However when I copy the code to Notepad++ and uncomment the submit line the code no longer works.